magento 2.4.5-p8 "The bucket doesn't exist" for custom filter
I add new filter using plugin for Magento\Framework\Search\Request\Config\FilesystemReader
Now sometimes I have error "The bucket doesn't exist." for added bucket.  After cache flush it works correct.
Due to caching - most of the time the filters are not displayed at all because there was an error when _getItemsData() for the new filter. The worst thing is that I can't reproduce it locally. Maybe someone has an idea why the error may occure periodically?
public function afterRead(
    \Magento\Framework\Config\ReaderInterface $subject,
    array $result
) {
    $requestNames = ['catalog_view_container', 'quick_search_container'];
    $attributeCode = 'vendor_stock_status';
    foreach ($requestNames as $requestName) {
        if (!empty($result[$requestName])) {
            $filterName = $attributeCode . '_filter';
            $butketName = $attributeCode . '_bucket';
            $queryName = $attributeCode . '_query';

            if (empty($result[$requestName]['queries'][$queryName])) {
                $result[$requestName]['queries'][$requestName]['queryReference'][] = [
                    'clause' => 'must',
                    'ref' => $queryName
                ];
                $result[$requestName]['queries'][$queryName] = [
                    'name' => $queryName,
                    'type' => 'filteredQuery',
                    'filterReference' => [
                        [
                            'clause' => 'must',
                            'ref' => $filterName
                        ]
                    ]
                ];
                $result[$requestName]['filters'][$filterName] = [
                    'name'  => $filterName,
                    'field' => $attributeCode,
                    'value' => '$'.$attributeCode.'$',
                    'type'  => 'termFilter'
                ];
                $result[$requestName]['aggregations'][$butketName] = [
                    'name'  => $butketName,
                    'field' => $attributeCode,
                    'type'  => 'termBucket',
                    'metric' => [
                        [
                            'type' => 'count'
                        ]
                    ]
                ];
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}


The problem was solved by replacing the plugin with the search_request.xml file with the code
<requests xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Search/etc/search_request.xsd">
<request query="catalog_view_container" index="catalogsearch_fulltext">
    <dimensions>
        <dimension name="scope" value="default"/>
    </dimensions>
    <queries>
        <query xsi:type="boolQuery" name="catalog_view_container" boost="1">
            <queryReference clause="must" ref="vendor_stock_status_query"/>
        </query>
        <query xsi:type="filteredQuery" name="vendor_stock_status_query">
            <filterReference clause="must" ref="vendor_stock_status_filter" />
        </query>
    </queries>
    <filters>
        <filter xsi:type="termFilter" name="vendor_stock_status_filter" field="vendor_stock_status" value="$vendor_stock_status$"/>
    </filters>
    <aggregations>
        <bucket name="vendor_stock_status_bucket" field="vendor_stock_status" xsi:type="termBucket">
            <metrics>
                <metric type="count"/>
            </metrics>
        </bucket>
    </aggregations>
    <from>0</from>
    <size>10000</size>
</request>
<request query="quick_search_container" index="catalogsearch_fulltext">
    <dimensions>
        <dimension name="scope" value="default"/>
    </dimensions>
    <queries>
        <query xsi:type="boolQuery" name="quick_search_container" boost="1">
            <queryReference clause="must" ref="vendor_stock_status_query"/>
        </query>
        <query xsi:type="filteredQuery" name="vendor_stock_status_query">
            <filterReference clause="must" ref="vendor_stock_status_filter" />
        </query>
    </queries>
    <filters>
        <filter xsi:type="termFilter" name="vendor_stock_status_filter" field="vendor_stock_status" value="$vendor_stock_status$"/>
    </filters>
    <aggregations>
        <bucket name="vendor_stock_status_bucket" field="vendor_stock_status" xsi:type="termBucket">
            <metrics>
                <metric type="count"/>
            </metrics>
        </bucket>
    </aggregations>
    <from>0</from>
    <size>10000</size>
</request>

